# Python INPUT command appears on the OUTPUT tab

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I give an INPUT command it appears in the OUTPUT tab of the Terminal and because it is in the OUTPUT tab it does not allow me to type anything.

How do I make it appear in the TERMINAL tab ...? I'm using Ubuntu with VSCODE Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What does your `launch.json` look like? You might find this post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671747/visual-studio-code-input-function-in-python

Comment: You could always try just running your code in an actual terminal (open terminal application, `cd` to directory, run `python3 <script name>.py`) to get sensible handling of stdin and stdout. [Perhaps have a look here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7vfj5h/how_is_the_input_function_supposed_to_work_visual/)

Comment: I tryed the n00dle suggestion but does not work.

Comment: Yes running it by open terminal it work. But I would like to run it by clicking on the Run Button like I do in VSCODE under Windows.

Answer (score -1):

if you taking Input from user you have to use a terminal even in windows you need to use terminal
open folder then type cmd in folder path

[image]

or through windows +R then cmd  and in terminal type
Python file.py  after opening the folder using cd command  to Run your script in terminal

**And To run code using vscode terminal you have to install shell cmd then select  it from the dropdownlist where it selected code in your photo**

**You need to know that output tab is just an real only editor you can't write in in**

Comment: OP is using Ubuntu, not Windows.

Comment: i know that  my answer still could help him or anyone else who use windows don't just down vote